# Windows web config redirect, different folder name and domain

Tags: windows, iis, redirect, asp.net, 301-redirect

I have 2 websites and a few thousands links with the same pattern that need to be redirected. I want to achieve this by writing the code one time and for it to work for all of the URLs.

This is the pattern I need to redirect from:

```
http://sub.domain1.com/index.cfm/pg/resources/lcid/358/_Example
```

This is the pattern I need to redirect to:

```
http://domain2.com/index.cfm/pg/resourceDetail/lcid/358/_Example
```

At the moment this is the way I am doing this but I have to do this for each page:

```
<rewrite>
<rewriteMaps>
<rewriteMap name="Redirects">
<add key="/index.cfm/pg/resources/lcid/358/_Example" value="http://domain2.com/index.cfm/pg/resourceDetail/lcid/358/_Example" />
</rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
```

Are there any better ways to do this without having to do it for each page?